# Get path of folder on right click in sidebar by Sublime API

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

How could I get path of folder on right click in sidebar by Sublime API? I can get path of file by sublime.view.file_name() but nothing for folders.

Comment: os.path.dirname (view.file_name ())

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, create a `Side Bar.sublime-menu` file with command definitions:

```
[
    { "caption": "Side Bar Test Dirs",  "command": "side_bar_test_dirs",  "args": {"dirs": []} },
    { "caption": "Side Bar Test Paths", "command": "side_bar_test_paths", "args": {"paths": []} },
    { "caption": "Side Bar test Files", "command": "side_bar_test_files", "args": {"files": []} },
]
```

And then the commands:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class SideBarTestDirsCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, dirs):
        print(dirs)

class SideBarTestPathsCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, paths):
        print(paths)

class SideBarTestFilesCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, files):
        print(files)
```

There is more detailed documentation in the [Sublime Text Unofficial Documentaion](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/menus.html).